# Http to Https but not in whole site

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a prestashop installation with multistore, so I have 2 domains to the same installation (different themes) , I have installed a SSL certificate to run in homepage and in forms pages as prestashop 1.5 recommends.

For example:

My url store for the store 1 is www.mystore1.com
My url store for the store 2 is mystore2.com

Now the certificate is working well, I can see the locks if I browse to https://www.mystore1.com and all load ok, but the problem is that there is no redirection to https when I browse to www.mystore1.com or mystore1.com. I have mod_rewrite ON and have regenerate the htaccess a few times.

This is my htaccess working for multistore, and I want to mod it:

```html
<IFMODULE mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mystore1.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mystore2.es$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I want to add http to https to mydomain1 only for the pages supported (home and forms). Please, can you help me to redirect www.mystore1.com and mystore1.com to https://www.mystore1.com.

I have tried with:

```html
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain1\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But only works for homepage, the no-https pages stops working and they should load as http without problems.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Having http and https version will lead you with a duplicate version and a possible penalty from Google.
You really should force Https everywhere with redirections via .htaccess or PHP.